# Program doesn't continue loop

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

When my program gets to the `while(!looking)` loop for the first time, it performs the task, but afterwards it doesn't continue on with taking the words and translating them. Need some help on figuring out why it doesn't run through.

```
while (cin.good()){
    getline(cin, lines); 
    while (!looking) {
        spot = lines.find(" "); 
        if (spot == -1){ 
            looking = true;
            spot = lines.length( ); 
        }
        line = lines.substr(0, spot); 
        TP1stLetter(line); 
        if (!looking)
            lines = lines.substr(spot + 1, lines.length( ) - spot + 1);
        }
        cout << endl;

//while( cin.good() ) {
    //getline (cin, line);
    //for(x = 0; x < line.size(); x++) {
        //char letter = line[x];
        //if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'e' || letter == 'i' 
        //      || letter == 'o' || letter == 'u'){
            //cout << letter;
        //}
    //}
    }
 }
```

Comment: did you try to debug it line by line?

Comment: Are you expecting us to "parse" your entire tool?

Comment: It looks like you aren't resetting `looking` to false

Comment: @Desolator I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @John Just mean your program is very large to ask about. You only better ask about portion of it which doesn't work.

Comment: @Desolator oh apologies, I wasn't entirely sure if I should have included it or not. I just didn't want to have something missing is all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add one line of code after the `cout` statement as follow:

```
if (mode == TOPIG) {
cout << "TOPIG MODE" << endl;
while (cin.good()){
    getline(cin, lines); 
    while (!looking) {
        spot = lines.find(" "); 
        if (spot == -1){ 
            looking = true;
            spot = lines.length( ); 
        }
        line = lines.substr(0, spot); 
        TP1stLetter(line); 
        if (!looking)
            lines = lines.substr(spot + 1, lines.length( ) - spot + 1);
    }
    cout << endl;
    looking = false;

    //while( cin.good() ) {
    //getline (cin, line);
    //for(x = 0; x < line.size(); x++) {  
    //char letter = line[x];
    //if (letter == 'a' || letter == 'e' || letter == 'i'
    //    || letter == 'o' || letter == 'u'){
    //cout << letter;
    //}
    //}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things I can think of, hope it helps
- Should you be setting looking = false at any point in your while(!looking) loop?
- Are you adding quote around your argument string in your command line
like this 
`YourExe.Exe these words are five arguments`

But instead you need quotes to make a string
 `YourExe.Exe "this is one argument"`

Comment: The argument is to determine topig or frompig, but working on topig; and I was hoping with cin.good and getlines, I would be able to continuous ask for lines to be translated. Also did you mean "Should you" or "Shouldn't you"?